# Concatenate YACC tokens

Tags: c, yacc, lexer

I am attempting to duplicate a C syntax where I can concatenate a variable number of strings into a single string like printf supports.  Here is an example:

```
log("here is line 1, "
    "and here is line 2");
```

I currently have the following that supports separate arguments:

```
| LOG LPAREN STRING COMMA STRING RPAREN {
  func($$, LOG, STR_ST, STR_ST, $3, $5); }
```

I would like to be able to concat multiple STRING tokens into a single string that can then be passed to func.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just need to use the usual separated-list production for your parameters.

```
LOG '(' PARAMS ')' {...} ;

PARAMS : STRING
       | PARAMS ';' STRING
       ;
```